# How to validate an input base on the value of another input field using stream transformers in flutter

Tags: authentication, flutter, dart, rxdart

I have a signup form with an email, password and confirm password fields. What I want to achieve is to validate the inputs correctly. For now I am using a naive algorithm to validate the email and password, and that's good. For the confirm password field, I want it to match the criteria of a valid password, and **the value should match that of the password**. Am I to use stream transforms or entirely a different approach?

**AUTHENTICATION BLOC**

```
  final _emailTFController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordTFController = TextEditingController();
  final _confirmPasswordTFController = TextEditingController();

  Stream<String> get emailStream =>
      _emailController.stream.transform(Validators.validateEmail);

  Stream<String> get passwordStream =>
      _passwordController.stream.transform(Validators.validatePassword);
```

**VALIDATORS**

```
import 'dart:async';

class Validators {
  static final validateEmail =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (email, sink) {
    if (email.contains('@')) {
      sink.add(email);
    } else {
      sink.addError('Enter a valid email');
    }
  });

  static final validatePassword = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (password, sink) {
    if (password.length > 4) {
      sink.add(password);
    } else {
      sink.addError('Invalid passord, please enter more than 4 characters.');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: May I ask where the ".stream" method comes from? How you transforming a `TextEditingController` into a stream?

Comment: The streams are coming from stream controllers not the text editing controllers as shown in the first part of the code. The stream controllers are rxdart Subject object, to be precise Behavior Subject.

Answer (score 0):

Use BehaviourSubject instead of Stream Controller

```
final passwordController=BehaviorSubject<String>();
```

And use ConfirmPassword function with doOnData method as below

```
Stream<String> get confirmpassword =>
      confirmpasswordController.stream.transform(confirmPasswordValidator)
          .doOnData((String c){
        // If the password is accepted (after validation of the rules)
        // we need to ensure both password and retyped password match
        if (0 != passwordController.value.compareTo(c)){
          // If they do not match, add an error
          confirmpasswordController.addError("Confirm Password donot match");
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        class PasswordManager{
            BehaviorSubject<String> _password =
                  BehaviorSubject<String>.seeded('');
            BehaviorSubject<String> _confirmPassword =
                  BehaviorSubject<String>.seeded('');
            String _confirmPass;
            
            
            //sink
            void setPassword(String pass) =>
                _password.sink.add(pass);
            
            void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPass) =>
                  _confirmPassword.sink.add(confirmPass);
            
            //get
            String getPassword() => _password.value;
            String getConfirmPassword() => _confirmPassword.value;
            
            //streams
            Stream<String> get isPasswordValid$ =>
                  _password.stream.doOnData((event) {
                    if (event.isEmpty) {
                      _confirmPassword.addError("*");
                    }
                    if (getPassword() != event) {
                      if (event == _confirmPass) {
                        setConfirmPassword(_confirmPass);
                      } else {
                        _confirmPassword.addError("*");
                      }
                    }
                  });
            Stream<String> get isConfirmPasswordValid$ =>
                  _confirmPassword.stream.doOnData((event) {
                    if (event.isEmpty) {
                      _confirmPassword.addError("*");
                    }
                    if (getPassword() != event) {
                      _confirmPassword.addError("*");
                    }
                    if (getConfirmPassword != null) {
                      _confirmPass = event;
                    }
                  });
            
            Stream<bool> get isPasswordAndConfirmPasswordValid$ => CombineLatestStream(
                  [isPasswordValid$, isConfirmPasswordValid$],
                  (value) => true);
    
            void dispose()
            {
               _Password?.close();
               _confirmPassword?.close();
            }
}
```